# Set italic and bold inside of \lstlisting

Tags: bold, italic, code

The following effect is what I want:
[image]

And I wrote corresponding code as below

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
\textbf{Document} ::= <Document [\textbf{\emph{documentName}}]$_0^1$  [\textbf{\emph{author}}]$_0^1$ [\textbf{\emph{date}}]$_0^1$>
                           [\textbf{Table}]$_1^n$  [\textbf{Action}]$_0^n$  [\textbf{Comment}]$_0^n$
                      </Document>                      
\end{lstlisting}
```

These code do worked, but It can't show italic and bold, the following is its result.
[image]

Thanks for your solutions!

Comment: maybe \lstset{ escapeinside={}} is useful. But I don't know the exact usage.  Waite for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have already enabled `mathescape`. This can also be used for executing `\textbf`, e.g. `$\textbf{Table}$`.

I would use markup commands, then the code is easier to read and maintain.
Also there are other options than a listings. The following example uses
a `tabbing` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}

\newcommand*{\EndTag}[1]{%
  \textless /#1\textgreater
}
\newcommand*{\StartTagBegin}[1]{%
  \textless #1%
}
\newcommand*{\StartTagEnd}{\textgreater}
\newcommand*{\Attribute}[1]{%
  \textbf{\itshape#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\AttributeSpec}[3]{%
  \Spec{\Attribute{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand*{\Element}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\ElementSpec}[3]{%
  \Spec{\Element{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand*{\Spec}[3]{%
  [#1]$_{\text{#2}}^{\text{#3}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\IsDefinedAs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  \Element{Document} \IsDefinedAs\ \= \StartTagBegin{Document}
    \AttributeSpec{documentName}{0}{1}
    \AttributeSpec{author}{0}{1}
    \AttributeSpec{date}{0}{1}\StartTagEnd
  \\
  \>\quad
    \ElementSpec{Table}{1}{n}
    \ElementSpec{Action}{0}{n}
    \ElementSpec{Comment}{0}{n}
  \\
  \> \EndTag{Document}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]